# Torque Sensor Project

Tags: microcontroller, c, microchip, mplabx

My group and I have been working on a Torque Sensor project using the PIC18F2431 chip, and we managed to write the code for each individual aspect on MPLAB for the Quadrature, ADC and LCD. Our concern right now is how to get the ADC value to display on the LCD.

Basically, we need to take our ADC values into decimal, but we are having trouble finding a suitable method for this. (We want to take a pot and adjust the values and see it real time on the LCD)

Comment: sprintf("%d", ADCvalue) doesn't work for you?

Comment: @brhans You are missing an argument. Should be sprintf(buf, "%d", ADCvalue); Or printf("%d", ADCvalue);

Comment: Careful - because `sprintf` has to deal with lots of different formatting strings it can be slow depending on implementation and features. Don't use it in an ISR.